# GitLab runner needs access to private user/client certificate

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We have a hosted GitLab instance internally and a Nexus repository hosted internally (neither of which touches the open internet). The Nexus repository uses client certificates for authentication. We have a repository in GitLab that is accessed by many developers and we need a way to get the user's client certificate in the runner so we can access Nexus.

Is there a way to specify in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` a user-specific mount? Putting the user's certificate information in the repository's "variables" is not an option because we have many developers accessing the same project. We (as developers) also don't have access to the runners. I can, however, create a new container/image that the GitLab runner can execute. Any thoughts on how to get the CI pipeline to recognize the user's certificate in the pipeline would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After reading the GitLab documentation and realizing how far behind we were in releases (a major version) I discovered that GitLab now integrates with Vault. This appears to work for exactly our use case.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/authenticating-with-hashicorp-vault/